# Movable Type: HASH output issue

Tags: movabletype

I am trying to combine and sort by date two different feed list of entries with hash but not seems to be working.

```
<mt:entries blog_id="1">
<$mt:entrydate format="%Y:%m:%d:%H:%M:%S" setvar="DateStart"$>
<mt:setvarBlock name="item{title}"><mt:entryTitle></mt:setvarBlock>
<mt:setvarBlock name="item{url}"><mt:entryPermalink></mt:setvarBlock>
<mt:setvarBlock name="items" key="$DateStart"><mt:var name="item"></mt:setvarBlock>
</mt:entries>

<mt:entries blog_id="2">
<$mt:entrydate format="%Y:%m:%d:%H:%M:%S" setvar="DateStart"$>
<mt:setvarBlock name="item{title}"><mt:entryTitle></mt:setvarBlock>
<mt:setvarBlock name="item{url}"><mt:entryPermalink></mt:setvarBlock>
<mt:setvarBlock name="items" key="$DateStart"><mt:var name="item"></mt:setvarBlock>
</mt:entries>

<mt:loop name="items" sort_by="key numeric reverse">
<$mt:Var name="__value__"$><br />
</mt:loop>
```

OUTPUT:

```
HASH(0x7fb66e8284a8)
HASH(0x7fb66e8284a8)
HASH(0x7fb66e8284a8)
```

What Am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works for me:

```
<mt:entries blog_id="9">
    <$mt:entrydate format="%Y%m%d%H%M%S" setvar="DateStart"$>
    <mt:SetHashVar name="myhash">
        <mt:SetHashVar name="$DateStart">
            <mt:entryTitle setvar="title">
            <mt:entryPermalink setvar="url">
        </mt:SetHashVar>
    </mt:SetHashVar>
</mt:entries>

<mt:entries blog_id="8">
    <$mt:entrydate format="%Y%m%d%H%M%S" setvar="DateStart"$>
    <mt:SetHashVar name="myhash">
        <mt:SetHashVar name="$DateStart">
            <mt:entryTitle setvar="title">
            <mt:entryPermalink setvar="url">
        </mt:SetHashVar>
    </mt:SetHashVar>
</mt:entries>

<mt:loop name="myhash" sort_by="key numeric reverse">
    Key: <$mt:Var name="__key__"$> — Values: <br>
    <mt:loop name="__value__">
        — Key: <$mt:Var name="__key__"$> — Value: <$mt:Var name="__value__"$><br>
    </mt:loop>
    <br>
</mt:loop>
```

It removes your "item" key which looks unnecessary to me.

P.S. I've also changed the date key to be a real number (since you want to sort by a numeric value).